# SQL Server select join detect if common column between two tables are different

Tags: sql-server, select, join

I am trying to write a function to check between two tables which have a common column with the same name and ID values.

Table 1: CompanyRecords

```
CompanyRecordsID   CompanyId  CompanyName  CompanyProcessID  
-----------------------------------------------------------
1                  222        Sears        123
2                  333        JCPenny      456
```

Table 2: JointCompanies

```
JointCompaniesID   CompanyId   CompanyName  ComanyProcessID
-----------------------------------------------------------
3                  222         KMart         123
4                  444         Walmart       001
```

They both use the same foreign key `CompanyProcessID` with value 123.

How do I write a select statement when it is passed the `CompanyProcessID` to tell if the `CompanyId` has changed for the same `CompanyProcessId`.

I assume it is a join between the two tables with `WHERE CompanyProcessID`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select max(case when cr.name = jc.name then 0 else 1 end) as name_not_same
from CompanyRecords cr join
     JointCompanies jc
     on cr.ComanyProcessID = jc.ComanyProcessID
where cr.ComanyProcessID = ?
```